# Display count for a day using counter metrics in data dog

Tags: microservices, metrics, datadog

We have a counter metric in one our micro services which pushes data to DataDog. I want to display the total count for given time frame, and also the count per day (X axis would have the date and Y axis would have count). How do we achive this?

I tried using `sum by` and `diff` with Query value representation. It gives the total number of the count for given time frame. But I would like to get a bar graph with the X axis as the date and the Y axis as the count. Is this possible in DataDog?

Comment: Maybe you need the `.rollup()` method? `.rollup(sum, 86400)` or something? I think that should work for this case. https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204526615-What-is-the-rollup-function-?mobile_site=true

Comment: Yes, I figured out  the same and solved it. I used diff(sum:<metric_name>.rollup(max, 86400))

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy considering you self-solved, would you mind posting the solution as an answer and self-accepting, so the question gets answered?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are 2 main questions here:

1. display the total count for a given time frame.
2. the count per day.

I think the [rollup method](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/rollup/) is going to be your friend for both questions.

For #1 you need to pass in the time frame you want a total over: `sum:<metric_name>.rollup(sum, <time_frame>)` and the single value can be displayed using the [Query Value](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/query_value/) visualization.

For #2 the datadog docs say you can get metrics per a day by

> graphed using a day-long rollup with .rollup(avg,86400)

So this would look something like `sum:<metric_name>.rollup(sum, 86400)` and can be displayed a Timeseries with bars.